# Playing a .mp4 file while writing it

Tags: wpf, http, video, mp4

This is a very simple task that I had such a hard time trying to do. My goal is pretty simple: send an mp4 file from my server to my client, and while its buffering and downloading I want to already play it. That means that I need to play a video.mp4 file while writing it, and I need it to display on some platform that I can control - like wxPython or WPF-Ironpython. Naturally, no such platform will let me play an open file for writing.

I have tried to implement and HTTP server (although totally unnecessary for my case, as I am writing an application-based Server-Client app) that would accept Range request, and when I run the server and load the URL on Chrome, it all works perfect and I can seek and buffering is great, but when I load it from WPF MediaElement it fails to play the video for some point (I cant really tell why as there is no documentation for this, any API, tutorials etc). I am really desperate.

I even thought about playing a video from a buffer and then just changing the buffer's content, but it doesn't seem like this possibility exists.

I am really stuck at this and I would love to get some suggestions. Please note that I am not a professional in this so I would appreciate if you could explain this to me in simple terms.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a background thread that does the downloading, while creating an http stream to the file to play it? (using HttpWebResponse.getResponseStream())

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. MP4 is not the correct container for your application. You must use something like HLS/dash/fragmented MP4.